# how to get virtual product data in product listing page and show in configurable product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list

I need to get all the child products details like id, name, sizes attribute from a configurable product id in a product listing page(list.phtml) page.

```
    <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

    //echo $product->getId(); //Main configurable product ID
    //echo $product->getName(); //Main Configurable Name

    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
        echo $child->getSku()."</br>"; //Child Product Sku    
    }
```

Above code is not working showing error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on null

Please help me how to show virtual product information of configurable product in product listing page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of: don't use the object manager directly. And your getting the error because `current_product` is not set on a product listing page.

If you look at `list.phtml`, you see a loop that iterates through the collection:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    // rendering of the product
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Inside this loop you can use `$_product->getTypeInstance()` as expected. But you most likely want to do an extra check:

```
if ($_product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') {
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
    foreach ($usedProducts as $childProduct) {
        // ... do your stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Please note that this kind of logic in your template can become very heavy very quickly so be careful what you do and/or make clever use of caching. Although the `getUsedProducts()`-method has internal caching.